Constructing squares
When proving inequalities, sometimes constructing squares can be helpful. For instance, when proving the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we can rewritten the expression as$$\bigg(\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i^2\bigg)\bigg(\sum\limits_{i=1}^nb_i^2\bigg)-\bigg(\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_ib_i\bigg)^2=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\bigg(a_i\sqrt{\sum\limits_{j=1}^nb_j^2}-\frac{\sum\limits_{j=1}^na_jb_j}{\sqrt{\sum\limits_{j=1}^nb_j^2}}b_i\bigg)^2\geq 0$$, which is the sum of n squares, and then it proves the inequality.
Another example is that for n positive numbers $x_1$, $x_2$,...,$x_n$, when proving $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^2\geq \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_ix_j$$, we can also rewritten the expression as $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^2- \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_ix_j=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\bigg(x_i-x_j\bigg)^2\geq 0$$, which is the sum of squares. Also, when proving $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^3\geq \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_ix_j^2$$, we can also rewritten the expression as $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^3- \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_ix_j^2=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i\bigg(x_i-x_j\bigg)^2$$. My question is that is it possible for any positive integers $p$, $q$, and n positive numbers $x_1$, $x_2$,...,$x_n$, we can write $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^{p+q}- \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^px_j^q$$ as the sum of some squares? If so, how to do that?

This holds by AM-GM, so I would expect a sum of squares to exist. But I don't think it will be a nice one.

I hope this makes sense.
Note that your inequality holds by AM-GM. More specifically,
$$\frac{px_i^{p+q}+qx_j^{p+q}}{p+q} \ge x_i^px_j^q$$
What you're trying to do is factorize the following expression so that it's obvious that it is positive if $x_i,x_j$ are positive.
$$px_i^{p+q}+qx_j^{p+q} - (p+q)x_i^px_j^q \ge 0$$
Rewrite this as
$$x_j^{p+q} \left( p\left(\frac{x_i}{x_j}\right)^{p+q} - (p+q)\left(\frac{x_i}{x_j}\right)^p+q\right) \ge 0$$
We are not interested in $x_i,x_j$ individually, rather we are interested in their ratio (as equality holds iff it is one). So, define $x = x_i/x_j$. Note that since $x_j^{p+q}$ is positive, we don't care much about it.
Now, you want to factorize
$$f(x) = px^{p+q} - (p+q)x^p + q \ge 0$$
If we can factorize this into a "nice" form, then we can just sum it for all such pairs $(i,j)$.
We can see that $x = 1$ is a root. Since we intuitively "know" it must be non-negative for $x \ge 0$ (and that there is no other positive root), $(x-1)^{2k}$ divides $f$ for some positive integer $k$. Let's show $k=1$.

Lemma: $f(x) = (x-1)^2 g(x)$, where $g$ is a polynomial with no positive roots. 
Proof: Clearly, $p(1) = 0$. Note that
$$f(x) = px^{p+q} - px^p - qx^p + q = px^p(x^q - 1) -q(x^p -1)$$
This is equivalent to
$$f(x) = (x-1)(px^p(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^{q-1}) - q(1+x+\ldots+ x^{p-1})$$
Note that the other factor is also zero at $x=1$. Hence $(x-1)^2$ divides $f$. Now, we show an higher power of $(x-1)$ does not divide $f$. Suppose it does. Then $f''(1)= 0$ (why?). However, we can see this is false as
$$f''(x) = p(p+q)((p+q-1)x^{p+q-2} - (p-1)x^{p-2}$$which is clearly non-zero at $x= 1$.  
Now, it remains to show that $g$ has no positive root. This follows by Descartes' rule of signs.

Ok, we're almost done, but there is one hitch. It is not easy to directly observe that $g$ is non-negative for positive $x$, although we "know" that it is so. Can we prove a stronger statement about $g$? Turns out we can!

Lemma: $g$ has non-negative coefficients. 
Proof: By polynomial long division, it is not hard to see that
$$g(x) = px^{p+q-2} + 2px^{p+q -3} + \ldots+ (q-1)px^p+  qpx^{p-1} + q(p-1)x^{p-2}+ \ldots +q$$

Now, you can happily write
$$\frac{px_i^{p+q}+qx_j^{p+q}}{p+q} -  x_i^px_j^q = \frac 1{p+q} \cdot(x_i-x_j)^2 ( \text{some polynomial with +ve coefficients})$$
and sum it for all $(i,j)$ to get the desired expression.

It is worth noting that the "some polynomial" mentioned above need not be computed by hand, instead, we can use the polynomial found for $g$ directly, by replacing $x$ with $x_i$ and multiplying each term by a power of $x_j$ so that each term has degree $p+q-2$. For example, when $p = 1,q = 3$, we get
$$\frac{x_i^4 + 3x_j^4}{4} - x_ix_j^3= \frac 14 \cdot (x_i-x_j)^2(x_i^2 + 2x_ix_j + 3x_j^2)$$

I think I've managed to construct the squares after many attempts. First I wanna talk about a special case, where $p=1$ and $q=3$. In this example, we need to write $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^4-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_ix_j^{3}$$ as the sum of squares.
First I notice that $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^2\bigg(x_i-x_j\bigg)^2=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^4-2\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^3x_j+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^2x_j^2$$ \begin{aligned}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_ix_j\bigg(x_i-x_j\bigg)^2=&\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^3x_j-2\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^2x_j^2+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_ix_j^3\\
=&2\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^3x_j-2\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^2x_j^2\end{aligned} Comparing the right-hand side with the original expression, the following becomes obvious $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^4-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_ix_j^{3}=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_ix_j\bigg(x_i-x_j\bigg)^2+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^2\bigg(x_i-x_j\bigg)^2$$
Notice that $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^2\bigg(x_i-x_j\bigg)^2=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_j^2\bigg(x_i-x_j\bigg)^2$$ because of symmetry, we can duduce that $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^4-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_ix_j^{3}=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\bigg(x_i^2+x_ix_j+x_j^2\bigg)\bigg(x_i-x_j\bigg)^2$$
Now because $x_i$ are all positive, we know that the left hand is positive.
A more general form is $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\bigg(x_i^px_j^q-x_i^{p-1}x_j^{q+1}\bigg)=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\bigg(x_i^{p-2}x_j^q+x_i^{p-3}x_j^{q+1}+...+x_i^qx_j^{p-2}\bigg)\bigg(x_i-x_j\bigg)^2 \tag{1}$$ for all $p,q\in\mathbb{N}^{*}$ and $p-1\geq q+1$ (this can be proved by induction). In this way, writing $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^{p+q}-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^px_j^q$$ is just a process of splitting the terms. For instance, if we're asked to construct squares for $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^{101}-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^{51}x_j^{50},$$ we just need to do the following \begin{aligned}&\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^{101}-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^{51}x_j^{50}\\
=&\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^{101}-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^{100}x_j^{1}\\
+&\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^{100}x_j^{1}-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^{99}x_j^{2}\\
+&...+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^{52}x_j^{49}-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_i^{51}x_j^{50}
\end{aligned} and then use (1) to solve the problem.
